# Using Enums to parse generic values in other classes

Tags: java, enums

I want to create an Enum class that contains a path, and a class type that I can then use to call another class and have the generic type of that already there.

For example:

```
public enum Settings {
    
    EXAMPLE_1("path here", Integer.class),
    EXAMPLE_2("path here", String.class);
    
    private String path;
    private Class<?> clazz;
    
    Settings(String path, Class<?> clazz){
        this.path = path;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    
    public Class<?> getClassType(){
        return clazz;
    }
    
}
```

Then, I would then use this to create another class using the types in this class, like so:

```
public class Setting <T> {
    
    private T value;
    
    public Setting(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
}
```

I've tried multiple different things, but I'm not sure how to go from the enum, containing the class type, to actually making the Setting class have that type initalised in it.

I then want to have a Map containing the Enum, and then the Setting class.
`private Map<Settings, Setting> settings = new HashMap<>();`

For example, then calling the enum EXAMPLE_2, would return the Setting class with a String, where as EXAMPLE_1 would return it as an Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums do not support generics, unfortunately. Generics are compiler-only constructs (well, class files can contain them, but they exist solely for a compiler working off of class files to do its thing), so you *must* have a situation where the compiler can link it together. Without enums having generics, you can't.

You have 2 broad options:

### Make a custom enum value type per value.

Each enum value can be its own little class. Which can override things from the enum as a whole which functions as a superclass of sorts. So, you could do this:

```
public enum Settings {
    EXAMPLE_1("path here") {
      public Class<Integer> getClassType() { return Integer.class; }
      public Setting<Integer> getSetting() {
        // write however you like it here
      }
    },
    EXAMPLE_2("path here") {
      // similar here
    },

    ;
    
    private String path;
    
    Settings(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    
    public abstract Class<?> getClassType();
}
```

But this still won't let you write methods that link things together. The above would let you write: `Setting<Integer> setting = Settings.EXAMPLE_1.getSetting();` without any issue, but you can't write something like:

```
public <T> T showSetting(Settings<T> sEnum) {
  return sEnum.getSetting().getValue();
}
```

i.e. where a method can be written that is ambivalent about the type of a setting but can 'convey' it across parameter to return type.

### Forget `enum`

enum is just syntax sugar. It's quite a big pile of syntax sugar, but most of that is to ensure that only one instance exists per value, *even if* you try to serialize them. If the serialization thing isn't relevant, ensuring 'only one value' is nearly trivial and the enum syntax sugar doesn't give you that much. You can't `switch` on it anymore, that's about it. When you handroll the enum type, you can get around the 'no generics' restriction.

```
public final class Settings<T> {
 private final String path;
 private final Class<T> type;

 public static final EXAMPLE_1 = new Settings<Integer>("path here", Integer.class);

 private Settings(String path, Class<T> type) {
   // private constructor - ensuring nobody can make them but this source file
   this.type = type;
   this.path = path;
 }

 public Class<T> getClassType() { return this.type; }
 public String getPath() { return this.path; }
 public Setting<T> getSetting() {
   return new Setting<T>(...);
 }
}
```

You can still write `Settings.EXAMPLE_1` the same way you'd do if Settings is an enum.